# Is it a good programming practice by returning expression as boolean?

Tags: syntax

Let's say I have a function f(x) that accepts integer x and return a boolean: whether x is greater than 3 or not.

There is one way to return this function:

```
bool f(int x){
  return x > 3;
}
```

Is it a good programming practice? And, is it commonly practiced?

Comment: Is there a reason why not?

Comment: You should probably just check if its > 3 where you want to do f().  It would make the code more readable.

Comment: Yes, its goog practice. and also u can try ternary operator(conditional operator).

Answer (score 1):

The implementation with only a return is fine since the functionality is simple and obvious.  The function name is not good, it should be more descriptive. 'f' doesnt tell us anything about what the function is supposed to be doing.

Answer (score 1):

It's all a bit opinionated but if you are SOLID principles then the answer is yes.

Reasons for yes are mostly centred around code reuse and visibility/readability.

On the other hand it may abstract logic too far away from where it's used.

Rule of hand if it's used in more than one place then yes otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

If you check comparison function in most languages, it will return an integer which describes the state `0 - equal`,`1 - greater`, `-1 - less`. The advantage of this is you can use the function in a sorting algorithm.
If this is relevant, you can use that approach.

Answer (score 0):

It is dependent on the function and what you want returned. If you are looking for the boolean to always be true it may be more practical to just put in an expression that is always true and vice versa.

In this situation it is reliant on how you want your program to read the data. This is a very simple example, however in a more complex program you could run into some problems.